# Getting JSON data from server and generating excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, excel

I'm trying to generate an excel file from a json object which I get from the server.

My code is as follows:

```
[Route("api/Generate")]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(dynamic jsonObject)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                var fileFormat = "xlsx";
                formData.Add(new StringContent("Test"), "FileName");
                formData.Add(new StringContent(fileFormat), "FileFormat");
                formData.Add(new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString()), "Data");

                var tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                if (!Directory.Exists(tempPath))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);

                var tempFilePath = Path.Combine(tempPath, String.Format("{0}.{1}", "Test", fileFormat));

                using (var newFile = File.Create(tempFilePath))
                {
                    //here's the error
                    jsonObject.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result.CopyTo(newFile);
                }
                var si = new ProcessStartInfo();
                si.CreateNoWindow = true;
                si.FileName = tempFilePath;
                si.UseShellExecute = true;
                Process.Start(si);

                return Ok();
            }
```

However when I try to test I receive the following error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot perform
>   runtime binding on a null reference'

Though jsonObject is not null, I've set a breakpoint on execution and it contains the data passed to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What it means "generate Excel file from JSON"? What did you do for it? I don't see any interactions with Excel.

Comment: Which line gives you error?

Comment: use this as reference https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/how-to-generate-excel-from-xml-and-json-data-using-c

Comment: The part where I commented above, jsonObject.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()...

Comment: use await with Async() method. Please refer this for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

Comment: It didn't work I still receive the same error